# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails with Join tables

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using Java 8 with Hibernate5/JPA2.

I get the following error when I try delete a `Job` object:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`www`.`subcategory`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SUBCATEGORY_CATEGORY` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`CATEGORY_ID`) REFERENCES `category` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON
>   UPDATE NO ACTION)

**tables**

```
+============+   +=================+   +================+
| job        |   |  job_category   |   |  category      |
+============+   +=================+   +================+
| ID         |   |  JOB_ID         |   |  ID            |
|            |   |  CAT_ID         |   |                |
+============+   +=================+   +================+

                 +==================+   +=================+
                 | job_subcategory  |   | subcategory     |   
                 +==================+   +=================+
                 |  JOB_ID          |   |  ID             |
                 |  SUBCAT_ID       |   |  CATEGORY_ID    |
                 +==================+   +=================+
```

A `Job` can have many `Categories`. A `Category` can have many `SubCategories`.

**Job.java**

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "job_category", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "CAT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") })
private Set<Category> categories;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "job_subcategory", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "SUBCAT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") })
private Set<SubCategory> subCategories;
```

**Category.java**

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "category")
private Set<SubCategory> subCategories;
```

**SubCategory.java**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
private Category category;
```

**JpaDao.java**

```
protected void remove(Job entity) {
    entityManager.remove(entity);
}
```

When I delete the `Job` object, I would like it to remove a row from the `job` table and the join tables (`job_category` and `job_subcategory`), but not the `category` and `subcategory` tables.

Any advise appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I try to remove the `subcategories` and `categories` and then the `job`:

```
public boolean delete(Job job) {
    Set<SubCategory> subCategories = job.getSubCategories();
    if (subCategories != null) {
        for (SubCategory subCategory : subCategories) {
            entityManager.remove(subCategory);
        }
    }
    Set<Category> categories = job.getCategories();
    if (categories != null) {
        for (Category category : categories) {
            entityManager.remove(category);
        }
    }
    entityManager.remove(job);
    return true;
}
```

But I still get the same error:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`www`.`job_subcategory`, CONSTRAINT `fk_job_sub_subcategory` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`SUBCAT_ID`) REFERENCES `subcategory` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

The error only occurs when I finish the Transaction (`@Transactional`), so it looks like it is when Hibernate performs the commit.

**UPDATE**

I try the following:

```
public boolean delete(Job job) {
    job.setSubCategories(null);
    job.setCategories(null);
    super.remove(job);
    return true;
}
```

but get the following again:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`www`.`person_job`, CONSTRAINT `fk_person_job_person` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`PER_ID`) REFERENCES `person` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO
>   ACTION)

**UPDATE**

I try:

```
public boolean delete(Job job) {
    job.setSubCategories(null); 
    job.setCategories(null);
    job.setPerson(null);        
    super.remove(job);
    return true;
}
```

and get:

> IllegalArgumentException: Source must not be null

Comment: Delete first categories and subcategories associated with the job. Then delete the job (all in a single transaction of course).

Comment: Thanks John, I tried that, but I still get an error. Please see I have updated above.

Comment: try to remove (I don't mean em.remove() here) from job's subcategories the reference to job (set it to null), and from job the references to subcategories (empty the set), before you delete the subcategory. Delete (em.remove()) the subcategory. Do the same with job's categories. Now delete the job.

Comment: Well, it is a different exception now. You have also a person in the db, and you have to eliminate the person-job link as well in the same manner probably (you don't show the relevant db part), in which you have done that with categories and subcategories.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice it was PERSON now.

Comment: I'm still doing something wrong, because I get the error: Source must not be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, try something like that

```
public boolean delete(Job job) {
    Set<SubCategory> subCategories = job.getSubCategories();
    if (subCategories != null) {
        job.getSubCategories().clear();
        for (SubCategory subCategory : subCategories) {
            subCategory.setJob(null);
            entityManager.remove(subCategory);
        }
    }
    Set<Category> categories = job.getCategories();
    if (categories != null) {
        job.getCategories().clear();
        for (Category category : categories) {
            category.setJob(null);
            entityManager.remove(category);
        }
    }
    job.setPerson(null);
    //if necessary:
    //Person.setJob(null);        
    entityManager.remove(job);
    return true;
}
```

Also, why do you have `super.remove(job)` and not `entityManager.remove(job)`, as in the code I just posted?

Do you still get an exception with this code?

Comment: If I do that, will it not delete from the Category and SubCategory tables?  I only want to delete from the join tables.

Comment: That works, thank you John.  I have marked this as the answer.  It does not delete from the Category & SubCategory tables. Only deletes the join tables as expected.  Thank you

Comment: "It does not delete from the Category & SubCategory tables. Only deletes the join tables as expected." - ok, glad that you got your code working. But perhaps the code you used is not precisely the code I posted, because as it is, entityManager.remove(subCategory) **should** delete the subcategory as well, and not only the record in the join table.

Answer (score 0):

This is typical SQL error. Even with pure SQL if you try to delete dependent rows along with parent in single query, yo will get this error.

First, delete (unlink) the relations (remove `category` and `subcategories` from `job`) then delete `job`. -- this is done in your update.

You have to remove `person` from `job` as well ;) and all other relations of `job` you didnt mention here.